# Ideas regarding lambda calculus

Tags: logic, soft-question, lambda-calculus

I want to work on lambda calculus as part of my MA thesis. What would be a suitable problem for me to tackle? I mean, what are the current research topics related to lambda calculus? What new results can a graduate student studying logic produce?

Comment: Like every area in mathematics, there are a lot open questions in the $\lambda$-calculus. Most of them are quite technical and not suitable for a MA thesis. By the way, without knowing your background and what you have already studied about the $\lambda$-calculus, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Producing original results is often not expected of a masters degree thesis author.  Do you have an advisor who works in this area?  They would be in the best position to approve a topic.  It would be important for Readers to better understand *your* background to give you any help.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have studied computer science as my bachelor studies where I studied basics of untyped and simply-typed lambda calculus. Now I am studying logic as my master studies. I am also familiar with the formal semantics of programming languages. Thus, I just know the basics or rather fundamentals of lambda calculus. Given this background, what would roughly be a suitable topic for me to pursue?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but you've omitted to mention whether you have an advisor to help you at this stage.  Please add more of your background to the Question itself, not just in a Comment as many Readers will not parse all the comments on a post.  Your brief note suggests your study of "lambda calculus" is related to programming.  I'd expect that in "studying logic" you've had occasion to search for open problems in $\lambda$-calculus, so a summary of what you found (and your reactions) would avoid unnecessary guesswork and explanation by Readers.

Comment: Like others said, follow the advice of your advisor.  But if I was to make a greedy request, I'd love to see someone create a version of lambda calculus that is based on functional composition rather than functional application, if that is possible.  The dual curry-howard type logic would be quite interesting.